# How do I change the order of solutions with my Discord bot?

Tags: python, random, discord, discord.py

This code is about making replies always appear in a different order in a message. But in the process everything gets mixed up.

A `random.choice` event for each of the answers `(A, B, C, D)` and the questions was created. I would like however only that the answer possibilities remain `random`, speak:

**1st attempt:**

*(9 is correct here)*

A) 9

B) 8

C) 7

*The answer given is "A", correct.*

**2nd run-up:**

A) 8

B) 9

C) 7

*Now "B" is given as the answer, that should also be counted as correct. How do I proceed?*

***My code:***

```py
        question_one = "How many lives do cat's have?"
        answers_one = {"9": "A", "1": "B", "10": "C"}


        questions = {question_one: {"9": answers_one}, "Is this working now?": {"A": {"Yes!": "A",
                                                                                       "No!": "B", "Maybe...": "C"}}}

        # get a question
        question = random.choice(list(questions.keys()))
        data = questions.get(question)
        correct_answer = list(data.keys())[0]
        answers = list(list(data.values())[0].items())
        question_msg = ""
        answers_msg = ""

        numbers_list = []
        answers_list = []

        for answer, number in answers:
            numbers_list.append(number)
            answers_list.append(answer)

        while numbers_list:
            num = numbers_list
            ans = random.choice(answers_list)
            answers_msg += f "**{num}) {ans}**\n"
            answers_list.remove(ans)
            numbers_list.remove(num)
```

My attempt was simply to remove the `random` function, but accordingly there is then no more list and nothing can be selected. My attempt to create a list also failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating through a list while removing or adding items to it is considered a bad practice.

You can use `random.shuffle` to shuffle the list and randomise how the options are displayed.

Another thing I noticed in your code was

`questions = {"How many lives do cat's have?": {"9": {"9": "A", "1": "B", "10": "C"}}, "Is this working now?": {"A": {"Yes!": "A","No!": "B", "Maybe...": "C"}}}`
In the first item, you are using `9` as the answer and in the second item, you are using `A` as the answer. If my understanding of your question is correct, you should be using `A` as the key for the first item. This is where you are probably going wrong.

The correct implementation:

```py
options = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] # if you want more options use string.ascii_uppercase
questions = {"How many lives do cat's have?": ['9', ['9', '1', '10']], "Is this working now?": ['Yes!', ['Yes!', 'No!', 'Maybe...']]}
question = random.choice(list(questions.keys()))
data = questions.get(question)
answer_options = data[1].copy()
random.shuffle(answer_options)
answer = data[0]
answer_option = options[answer_options.index(answer)] #gets correct option from options
answer_msg = ""
for i, option in enumerate(answer_options):
   answer_msg += f"{options[i]}) {option}"
#check if user input is equal to answer_option
```

Comment: Looks good so far, the only error I now get is: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'`. I tried to solve it by removing `answer_options =`  but that would cause an error with the rest of the code.

Comment: @Dominik, `random.shuffle` shuffles the list itself and does not return a new list. I edited my code and it should work now.

Comment: Still the same error - `Cannot find reference 'index'  in 'None'`. `answer_option` seems to be wrong. Also maybe add a `]`  to the last bracket in line `questions`.

Comment: made the same mistake again, `random.shuffle` does not return anything. it just modifies the passed list